# Docker memory leak with sonarqube

Tags: linux, docker, memory-leaks, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I am trying to run a docker container which contains SonarQube.

After build container, I did below command to run the container. For first several moment it looks fine(I guess since I can find `up` status in `docker ps -a`), but I exit automatically exit.

I have typed command like ...

```
docker run -d --name sonarqube 
    -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 
    -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar 
    -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar 
    -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL="jdbc:mysql://111.222.33.444:3306/sonar?characterEncoding=utf8&useUnicode=true&rewriteBatchedStatements=true" 
    sonarqube
```

And follow is failure log

```
2017.04.21 06:39:37 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[Pip the Troll][[timer]]] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool$EstimatedTimeThread.run(ThreadPool.java:747)
2017.04.21 06:39:37 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[Pip the Troll][scheduler][T#1]] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017.04.21 06:39:37 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[Pip the Troll][transport_client_worker][T#1]{New I/O worker #1}] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
 sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:434)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017.04.21 06:39:37 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[Pip the Troll][transport_client_worker][T#2]{New I/O worker #2}] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
 sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:434)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017.04.21 06:39:37 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[Pip the Troll][transport_client_worker][T#3]{New I/O worker #3}] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
 sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:434)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

After all, it seems like main cause of auto shutdown is `memory leak`. How can I fix this?

FYI, without `JDBC` information, it works fine.

================= EDIT ==================

Maybe I should provide more information to fix this. 
When I type `docker run` and immediately `docker logs sonarqube`, log looks like ...

```
[root@DCSF-DEV08 ice]# docker logs sonarqube
01:00:46.930 [main] WARN org.sonar.application.JdbcSettings - JDBC URL is recommended to have the property 'useConfigs=maxPerformance'
2017.04.24 01:00:47 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2017.04.24 01:00:47 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /opt/sonarqube/temp/sq-process7897977644818879465properties
2017.04.24 01:00:47 INFO  es[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting es
2017.04.24 01:00:47 INFO  es[][o.s.s.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2017.04.24 01:00:47 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] version[2.4.4], pid[45], build[fcbb46d/2017-01-03T11:33:16Z]
2017.04.24 01:00:47 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] initializing ...
2017.04.24 01:00:47 INFO  es[][o.e.plugins] [sonarqube] modules [], plugins [], sites []
2017.04.24 01:00:47 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.env] [sonarqube] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/opt/sonarqube/data (/dev/mapper/centos-root)]], net usable_space [7gb], net total_space [49.9gb], spins? [possibly], types [xfs]
2017.04.24 01:00:47 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.env] [sonarqube] heap size [989.8mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
2017.04.24 01:00:49 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] initialized
2017.04.24 01:00:49 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] starting ...
2017.04.24 01:00:49 INFO  es[][o.e.transport] [sonarqube] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9001}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9001}
2017.04.24 01:00:49 INFO  es[][o.e.discovery] [sonarqube] sonarqube/GPO7RRqHR8a8tfu1KfgVtw
```

But after few seconds, the error happens and exit. The first error is something related with `ElasticSearch`.

```
2017.04.24 01:00:52 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] started
2017.04.24 01:00:52 INFO  es[][o.e.gateway] [sonarqube] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
2017.04.24 01:00:52 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
2017.04.24 01:00:52 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonarqube/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonarqube/temp/sq-process8670082336569494309properties
2017.04.24 01:00:53 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2017.04.24 01:00:53 INFO  web[][o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2017.04.24 01:00:54 INFO  web[][o.e.plugins] [Immortus] modules [], plugins [], sites []
2017.04.24 01:00:54 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.EsClientProvider] Connected to local Elasticsearch: [127.0.0.1:9001]
2017.04.24 01:00:54 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.LogServerVersion] SonarQube Server / 6.3.0.19869 / 43ea4f4c43aa89d4c435017f86d0da254e115e6b
2017.04.24 01:00:54 INFO  web[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:mysql://125.131.88.156:3306/sonar?characterEncoding=utf8&useUnicode=true&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
2017.04.24 01:00:55 ERROR web[][o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Unsupported mysql version: 5.5. Minimal supported version is 5.6.
2017.04.24 01:00:55 ERROR web[][o.a.c.c.StandardContext] One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2017.04.24 01:00:55 ERROR web[][o.a.c.c.StandardContext] Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2017.04.24 01:00:55 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[Immortus][[timer]]] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool$EstimatedTimeThread.run(ThreadPool.java:747)
2017.04.24 01:00:55 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[Immortus][scheduler][T#1]] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017.04.24 01:00:55 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[Immortus][transport_client_worker][T#1]{New I/O worker #1}] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
 sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:434)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I think JDBC url looks fine. I can access the database with sqllite.

Thanks for answering my errors.

Comment: These errors are caused by an early crash of SonarQube's web application in embedded Tomcat during its startup. Look up earlier in the logs to find the cause of the crash (most likely the jdbc settings are wrong)

Comment: Thanks @Seb-SonarSourceTeam. I will check it out for the former logs. If you do not mind, may I ask one more additional question? The jdbc option `characterEncoding`, `useUnicode`, `rewriteBatchStatements` is always necessary ?

Comment: @Seb-SonarSourceTeam I append some additional informations. Would you check that out for me? Thank!

Comment: @Seb-SonarSourceTeam. I am using mariadb ver `10.1.22`. The document said it is compatible with mysql ver `5.6`. However, sonarqube mesage like `Unsupported mysql version: 5.5. Minimal supported version is 5.6` . How could I avoid this validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change my database system form MariaDB ver.10.1.22 to MySQL ver.5.7. There are some posts about this problem, but it seems does not solved yet. For now Sonarqube can not be used with some version of MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly database connectivity issue. Check your address for typos and make sure your credentials are valid.